# What is the proper way to install and wire this outdoor light?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, siding

I have already installed this light, but feel like I am missing something and would like to make this a learning experience for myself and possibly others. [This](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075MY11PQ) is the light in question:

[image]

My **first question**, is that unlike all other outdoor lights I've seen, this one does not come with any sort of gasket to seal the rectangular base to the wall. Is this to code? Is there some sort of universal best practice for these type situations as I could not find a gasket of the right size?

I have vinyl siding, and purchased [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ply-Gem-12-6-in-x-7-8-in-Large-Mounting-Block-Wicker-FMBLKHA7H/202674758) large vinyl mounting block:
[image]

I cut a rectangular hole in my siding, drilled a 4" hole in the mounting block, mounted a [round metallic weatherproof electrical box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-1-2-in-Gray-5-Holes-4-in-Round-Weatherproof-Box-WRB550G/300846812) onto the sheathing and then installed the mounting block with the electrical box coming out of the hole I drilled (they are almost the same depth so they are more or less flush with one another.

[image]

The light came with your standard cross bar swivel type mount, which I mounted onto the electrical box.

[image]

Now here is my **second multi part question**: I have a ground wire coming from the wall, a ground wire coming from the light, a ground screw in my metal electrical box and a ground screw on the cross bar mount. From my understanding all metal components should be grounded to one another.

2.a. Is the correct way to run the ground wire from the light to the ground screw on the crossbar mount, then a wire from the crossbar mount ground screw to the electrical box ground screw and finally connect the house ground wire to this screw as well?

2.b. Or is it best to connect pigtails to each ground screw and then all the ground wires together in a single connection?

2.c. Is the crossbar being bolted to the electrical box already a grounding connection so only one of the ground screws need to be connected?

Comment: Ground the wire from the wall to the box, ground the wire from the lamp to the crosspiece.  The screws attaching the crosspiece to the box will provide ground continuity.

Comment: @Huesmann Got it, thank you!

Comment: To the gasket question: just use a bead of clear exterior caulk (silicone or a paintable like dynaflex 230) on the top and sides. (Not the bottom, so errant moisture can drain.)

Comment: Well, I would simply get some thin weatherstripping foam like this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-3-8-in-X-3-16-in-X-10-ft-Black-High-Density-Rubber-Foam-Weatherstrip-Tape-R338H/100197882 and run a strip across the back of the lamp mounting plate.  Do an upside-down U, leaving the bottom open.  Easier to remove the lamp than with sealant.